# What information do we know about Sherlock's newest character?

Tags: character, sherlock

What do we know about

> Sherlock's sister?

When was she born? The actress is younger than Cumberbatch and Gatiss so if she's supposed to be younger why did Sherlock forget about her?

If she's supposed to be older than both boys and an arrestable age that would put Sherlock at an age that he should have remembered her.

Why was she taken away/dealt with by Mycroft? Whatever she did was very serious as Lady Smallwood knows of it too, but Mycroft was in denial she did it so it must have been surprising and seemed disputable at first.

If Mycroft could still be in contact with her if he wished to be the punishment wasn't life long.

Why does she use "Miss me?" like Moriarty were they connected or did she make the broadcast of "Miss me?" and attached Moriarty to gather extra attention?

Comment: Please don't put spoilers in titles.

Comment: There's about 4 different questions here. You would do better to split them up into separate questions.

Comment: Sound too broad and opinion based both to me.

Comment: You are basically asking questions which will probably be answered next week.

Answer (score 2):

Diegetically we know very little about the character, but from a real world standpoint we know the character was planned during the production of series three;

'Euros' (the sisters name) is the name of a Greek God that brings ill fate, and is often associated with the 'eastern wind', which brings rain. The imminent arrival of an east wind has been mentioned already in Sherlock, when he tells Watson; “the east wind takes us all in the end.”, but was dismissed as it was considered to be a reference to the source material (from A.C. Doyle's *His last vow*;

> There’s an east wind coming all the same, such a wind as never blew on
>   England yet. It will be cold and bitter, Watson, and a good many of us
>   may wither before its blast. But it’s God’s own wind none the less,
>   and a cleaner, better, stronger land will lie in the sunshine when the
>   storm has cleared.

**However**, it was repeated in relation to the supposed resurrection of Moriarty by Watson in the same episode; after Mary questions how he is still alive, John replies; “Well if he is, he'd better wrap up warm. There's an east wind coming.”

It's plausible to deduct from this that Sherlock knows about his sister, and is aware she is plotting some kind of revenge.